Deriving a Linear System from the Autocovariance Function in Spectral Analysis of Univariate Time Series
I am currently studying Spectral Analysis for Univariate Time Series by Donald B. Percival and Andrew T. Walden, and I am working with a time series model represented by the following equations.
I am trying to express $\sigma_j^2$ in Equation (8c) in terms of $\{ \rho_\tau \}$ and $\sigma^2$. Below are the relevant equations:
I am trying to express $\sigma_j^2$ in Equation (8c) in terms of $\{ \rho_\tau \}$ and $\sigma^2$. Below are the relevant equations:
First, we have the autocovariance function $\rho_\tau$:
$$
\rho_\tau = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \sigma_j^2 \cos(2\pi f_j \tau)}{\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \sigma_j^2}.
$$
Also, the time series $X_t$ is given by:
$$
X_t = \mu + \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor} \left[A_j \cos(2\pi f_j t) + B_j \sin(2\pi f_j t)\right],
$$
where $A_j$ and $B_j$ represent the coefficients corresponding to the cosine and sine components, respectively, and $f_j$ are the frequencies defined as $$
f_j = \frac{j}{N} \quad j = 0, \dots, \ N.
$$
In addition,
$$
\sigma_{j}^2 = E[A_j^2] = E[B_j^2]  \quad E[A_j \cdot A_l] = E[B_{l} \cdot B_j] = \delta_{j, \ l} \quad E[A_l \cdot B_k] = 0.  
$$
I need to show how $\sigma_j^2$ can be expressed in terms of $\{ \rho_\tau \}$ and $\sigma^2$. Any help or guidance on how to derive this would be greatly appreciated!
I suspect I should be able to say that the following system is invertible, but how?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho_0 \\
\rho_1 \\
\rho_2 \\
\vdots \\
\rho_{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot \sigma^2
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\cos(2\pi f_1) & \cos(2\pi f_2) & \cos(2\pi f_3) & \cdots & \cos(2\pi f_{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor}) \\
\cos(4\pi f_1) & \cos(4\pi f_2) & \cos(4\pi f_3) & \cdots & \cos(4\pi f_{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor}) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\cos(2\pi \lfloor N/2 \rfloor f_1) & \cos(2\pi \lfloor N/2 \rfloor f_2) & \cos(2\pi \lfloor N/2 \rfloor f_3) & \cdots & \cos(2\pi \lfloor N/2 \rfloor f_{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 \\
\sigma_2^2 \\
\sigma_3^2 \\
\vdots \\
\sigma_{\lfloor N/2 \rfloor}^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
